# Passing an annotation from one view to another in swift

Tags: swift

I'd like to pass an annotation from ViewController to ARViewController and display it on the map. I receive a Nil error message when I hit the segue button :( Here's what i have in the ViewController

```
var startPt = POIs(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double("")!, longitude: Double("")! ))

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView,
    calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
    let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier : "ARV")
    self.present(viewController, animated: true)
  //location.mapItem().openInMaps(launchOptions: launchOptions)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    //guard let ViewController = segue.destination as? ARViewController,
    if segue.identifier == "ARV"{

        let vc = segue.destination as! ARViewController
        vc.dest = startPt
    }
}
```

And this is what I have in ARViewController

```
var dest = POIs(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double("")!, longitude: Double("")! ))


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    //show the user's current location
    mapView.userTrackingMode = .follow

    mapView.delegate = self as? MKMapViewDelegate

    mapView.addAnnotation(dest)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are manually presenting the destination view controller, not performing a segue, so `prepare(for:sender:)` will not be called.

You have two options:

1. Just set the `dest` property right there in `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` before you present, e.g.:

   ```
   let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier : "ARV") as! ARViewController
   viewController.dest = ...
   ```

   or
2. Don’t instantiate the view controller, but rather programmatically perform the segue that you’ve defined between these two view controllers (in this case, I’m assuming you’ve given the segue, itself, its own storyboard identifier of `ARV`), e.g.

   ```
   performSegue(withIdentifier: "ARV", sender: self)
   ```

   If you do this, `prepare(for:sender:)` will be called. FWIW, I’m not seeing where you’re setting `startPt`, though...